# Code to obtain quarter of a given value X is implemented as (x*64)/255 instead of (x*1)/4

Tags: c

I found an implementation wherein in order to obtain a quarter of a value X, following code was employed to run on ARM 32-bit processor.

```
   //global typedef
   typedef unsigned char  uint8;

   //Function definition
   uint8 FindQuarter(void)
   {   
     uint8  value, OneQuarter,ThreeQuarter;
     value = 100;      
     OneQuarter = (value * 64) / 255;// why not "(value * 1)/4" or "value/4"
     ThreeQuarter = (value *192) /255; //why not "(value * 3)/4"
     return 1; 
   }
```

Why somebody wants to using 64/255 or 192/255 instead of 1/4 or 3/4 although both is going to give approximately same result.
Note : Accuracy of calculation is not prime important here.It is allowed to deviate a little.

Comment: It won't be the same result, `64/255 != 64/256`

Comment: the result will **always** be 0

Comment: still for `value` 255: ( 255 * 64 ) / 255 = 64 is not equal to 255 / 4 = 63

Comment: My guess is that they were trying to be clever to avoid floating point computations and they wanted to have the ceil(quarter).

Comment: I'd rather ask why they didn't just write `quarter = value >> 2`??

Comment: @Dariusz the post has been edited please have a relook.

Comment: I don't think any of us will be able to understand why this was done without knowing what it is being used for.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the question was edited after Lu'u commented. Based on Lu's comment I realized mistake in my question which was subsequently edited.

Comment: @mfro That would be almost worse. The proper way, with no magic and a "surprise factor" of 0, is of course `quarter = value / 4;`. Bit-shifting happens to map to division, but that's not as clear as an actual division. The compiler is smart enough to insert a shift if that helps.

Comment: @Degustaf . The use case is, I have two values namely X and Y. The idea is to obtains a value Z wherein  Z = X(1/4) + Y(3/4)

Comment: @unwind: a C programmer that does not immediately understand right shifts as division by a power of two does not deserve that title (my opinion). Other than that, you are perfectly right: optimization should be left to the compiler until it turns out it needs some help. But not before.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the original code is `value * (64 / 255)`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yep, OP mentioned that. deleted my comment.

Comment: In the original code, is `value` really a `uint8_t`? Or is it somehow derived from a fixed-point or floating-point fraction? Also, is this in the context of merging colours?

Comment: Does it come from a statistic analysis ? The only use case for a `n-1` denominator that comes to mind is statistic variance ... If not, I can only imagine a way to defeat compiler optimisation and ensure that it will *really* use a division instead of a shift, for example to build a time consuming operation (sometimes used in password checking)

Comment: @rici  this was found in an implementation to determine the weighted average for received signal strength.

Answer (score 2):

What did the orignal author meant by 'Quarter'?  When calculating some values a pattern emerges:

```
f(0) = 0x00 (0)
f(1) = 0xC0 (192)
f(2) = 0x80 (128)
f(3) = 0x40 (64)
f(4) = 0x00 (0)
f(5) = 0xC0 (192)
...
f(254) = 0x80 (128)
f(255) = 0x40 (64)
```

This could be interpretted as assigning a 'quarter' of the domain of a byte to each input value, where each quarter is defined by the lowest value in that subset.  (It certainly isn't a divide by four.)

**EDIT**

The answer above in inaccurate (at best) or, more probably, incorrect.

Following up on a comment, it appears that my implementation of `f()` was incorrect, with the `/ 255` part of the calculation being 'optimised' and performed as a signed division by -1.

```
typedef unsigned char  uint8; 
int main (void)
{
    short ui16Value;
    for(ui16Value = 0; ui16Value < 0x100; ui16Value++)
    {
        uint8 value = (uint8)ui16Value;
        // definition of f():
        uint8 quarter =  (value * 64) / 255;
        printf("f(%d) = 0x%2.2X (%u)\r\n", value, quarter, quarter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Disassembly:

```
!        uint8 quarter =  (value * 64) / 255;
0xF48: MOV.B [W14+2], W5
0xF4A: MOV #0xC0, W4      <-- this looks odd.
0xF4C: MUL.SS W5, W4, W4
0xF4E: MOV.B W4, [W14+3]
```

The line highlighted above looks like an operator precidence issue, with 64 having been divided by 255 == 0xFF == -1, before the multiplication in the brackets.

Explicitly stating the value as being unsigned results in the values all being zero.

```
!        uint8 quarter =  (value * 64) / (uint8)255;
0xF48: MOV.B [W14+2], W4
0xF4A: ZE W4, W4
0xF4C: SL W4, #6, W5
0xF4E: MOV #0xFF, W4
0xF50: REPEAT #0x11
0xF52: DIV.SW W5, W4
0xF54: MOV W0, W4
0xF56: MOV.B W4, [W14+3]
```

I may have to look at the errata for the version of compiler I'm using, or try compiling for the target micrcontroller instead of the simulator.  Either way, it's something interesting for me to look into.

Comment: The values are unsigned, so -64 should be 192

Comment: @Degustaf Thanks.  I should pay more attention to my `printf` output formatting.  :-)

Comment: what is your definition of f? (1*64)/255 is 0, not 192.

Comment: @rici my definition of `f()` was incorrect, apparently.  I've explained in the edit to my answer.  (You can reproduce the results - very artifically - by using Micrsoft Calculator in Programmer View with the Byte radio selected.)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the original programmer decided the value `255` should be a special case.

`255` probably means 100% of something in your software, so he felt that treating it as if it were the un-representable value `256` was the best way of handling the value.

Your code is *almost* equivalent to...

```
OneQuarter = value == 255 ? 64 : value / 4;
ThreeQuarter = value == 255 ? 192 : value * 3 / 4
```

Comment: `ThreeQuarter = (value *192) /255;` is not the same as `value == 255 ? 192 : value * 3 / 4`,  try `value = 254`.  Still like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume this code deals with something like colours/pixels; where 0x00 is minimum and 0xFF is maximum.

If that's the case, the value 255 actually represents "255/255 of maximum", and a quarter really should be calculated as `value = (value/255.0)/4 * 255.0` (or more generally, `value = (value/MAX)/4 * MAX`). Of course floating point is often slower, and `value = (value * 64)/255` is a good "integer only" approximation.

Note that this is entirely about rounding correctly. Integer division truncates, and dividing by 4 doesn't give you the closest answer (e.g. 3/4 == 0 and doesn't give you "0.75 rounded up to 1").

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tests, and the only difference that's looks important is that for `value = 255`, the total result would be `OneQuarter + ThreeQuarter = 256`.

But if precision is important, than this technique will result better values.

If you validate the result with the sentence `Z == X(1/4) + Y(3/4)`, for the above technique the result will match for 128 values between 1 and 255. For a simple division, the result will not be valid for 192 cases.